CiviMail clickthrough links being classified as malicious by Windows Defender
We've been using clickthrough tracking for many years as a way to gauge interest in the emails we send to our contacts (they are mainly businesspeople). As far back as I can remember this has worked pretty well. However in the last few days I'm getting a number of reports from people saying that they are seeing warning alerts about the potentially malicious nature of the link they've clicked. The clearest example I seen to date involves Microsoft Defender for Office 365 and its 'Safe Links' mechanism.
The user clicks a perfectly harmless link in an email we've sent them and they get a massive on-screen alert telling them that the website is classified as malicious.
The same user reports that if they visit the actual URL rather than the clickthrough-encoded URL there is no issue.
On the face of it this might well be Microsoft, in its inimitable way, setting rules to suit itself. In which case there is likely little that we can do about it other than disable clickthrough tracking.
But I'm posting about it here to see a) if this is an issue that others are seeing, and/or b) if there's anything useful that we can do address this other than by disabling the clickthrough tracking.
